# Unable to get Access Token Via Fiddler IdentityServer3

Tags: claims-based-identity, identityserver3, membershipreboot

I can successfully call my Api via a web browser. Using IdentityModel works fine.
But when I try to call the Api via Fiddler I get invalid_client. My client information comes from a database based on the MembershipReboot Client tables.

I tried passing data via the Post Body and via Authentication basic. Both fail.

When calling using Authentication Basic encoded parameters I have the following>

```
    User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: qaquasaridentity
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic  dGVzdC5hcGk6c2VjcmV0
```

The actual encoded value in Fiddler shows:

```
    No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.

Authorization Header is present: Basic  dGVzdC5hcGk6c2VjcmV0
Decoded Username:Password= test.api:secret
```

When I call using the Post Body for parameters the data passed is:

```
client_id=test.api
&client_secret=secret
&grant_type=client_credentials
&scope=testapi
```

The Server log says

```
2017-01-20 12:06:13.968 -06:00 [Debug] Start client validation
2017-01-20 12:06:13.971 -06:00 [Debug] Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2017-01-20 12:06:13.973 -06:00 [Debug] Start parsing for secret in post body
2017-01-20 12:06:13.973 -06:00 [Debug] No secret in post body found
2017-01-20 12:06:13.976 -06:00 [Debug] Start parsing for X.509 certificate
2017-01-20 12:06:13.976 -06:00 [Debug] client_id is not found in post body
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2017-01-20 12:06:13.976 -06:00 [Information] Parser found no secret
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2017-01-20 12:06:13.981 -06:00 [Information] No client secret found
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2017-01-20 12:06:13.983 -06:00 [Information] End token request
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2017-01-20 12:06:13.988 -06:00 [Information] Returning error: invalid_client
```

[image]
I have the client_id and client_secret but the error log says otherwise.
Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? I can get my access_token via .NET on the backend but not via Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

[image]The token endpoint does not take JSON, but form-data.

```
POST /connect/token

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=test.api&client_secret=secret&scope=api
```

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest
https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/token.html

Comment: I get the same error doing that as well. But the error log now says invalid hashing algorithm. I am providing the information via the PostBody as in your example.

Comment: Looks like there's en extra white space between "Basic " and your base64 encoded clientid:clientsecret. Could that be it?

Comment: Isn't Authentication basic optional? if I use the PostBody as in your example then I do not need Authentication Basic XXXXX. Correct?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong - it works fine against the demo site (see pic)

Comment: The error of "invalid hashing algorithm"  : how are you storing the secrets? Are they stored hashed using sha256 or sha512?

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/93bc6bc9b536146b9e3fa0bed21d77283d07f788/source/Core/Validation/HashedSharedSecretValidator.cs#L85

Comment: Yes it is stored as a Sha256 hash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133698/discussion-between-john-korsnes-and-nate).

Comment: I will contact you via the chat in the morning. Thanks

Comment: did this get resolved? i have a client_credential grant type with the same issue.